# How do I call a postgresql stored function using FluentNHibernate which returns refcursor

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

How to call stored functions of postgresql using NHibernate, which returns setof refcurosr please help to find the solution of my problem...

Answer (score 1):

[see here](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/11/01/stored-procedures-with-fluent-nhibernate/). basicly you'll probably need to mimx Fluent and xml. Otherwise use `Sql...()` methods in `ClassMap<>`

Comment: thanks for your response but My need is using postgresql how to call stored procedure

Comment: did you try it with named query or with sql...() ? What is the error?

Comment: i'm trying with NamedQuery i found Field Not Found Exception every time

Comment: which field? stacktrace? is this really a problem with calling the sproc or with the mapping to the object?

Comment: while calling with stored procedure at the name of the sproc the error is as follows  Could not execute the query                    [ select patient_id as "PatientID",first_name as "FirstName",last_name as "LastName" from getname(:p0); ]
  Name:FirstNameParam - Value:c

Comment: in above getname() is stored function

Comment: where is the actual error? you posted only the which operation failed but not the error message/code why it failed. Does the sproc really return a refcursor with `patient_id, first_name, last_name`?